# how can i draw something on my Sprite?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am using cocos2d to develop a game, now have a sprite loaded from image, and i would like to draw something on it like square? how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

1. Create a new CocosNode class. Call it CustomDrawNode
2. in the draw method of that class I would use drawline to draw what I need.
3. In the GameScene where you init your sprite, also init an instance of your CustomDrawNode.
4. Add it to the scene with: [self addChild:myCustomDrawNode z:1000 tag:999]. Use a higher z than the sprite.
5. Move your instance of CustomDrawNode to the same position as the sprite.

Comment: You may want to add it as a child of the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the Sprite class and override the draw method.